# Hamming distance and parity

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code, bit-manipulation

For an Hamming code of $n$ bit there are $k$ bit reserved for the data and $p$ bit for the parity where $p$ is the minimum integer for which the following inequation is satisfied: $$2^p \geqslant p + k + 1$$ 
This because at least $p$ bit are required to code $n$ error on a single bit $+ 1$ for the "no error" word.

For an Hamming code with distance $d$ you can detect $d-1$ bit of errors and correct $\lfloor d-1/2 \rfloor$ bit of errors.

However you can have **SEC (7,4)** and **SEC (12,8)** with the same Hamming distance $d = 3$ but the the first has $p = 3$ bit for the parity while the second has $p = 4$ bit for the parity.

The first question is what does it mean for an Hamming code H having an Hamming distance = 3 ? Does it mean that all $k$ or $n$ bit of data are required to have $d=3$ with each other ?

What is the relationship between the parity and the distance in an Hamming code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (binary) code $C$ is a collection of binary strings of some length $n$, known as *codewords*. The minimal distance of $C$ is the minimum Hamming distance between (different) codewords. Hamming codes have minimum distance 3, which means that (1) every two codewords differ in at least 3 places, (2) there exist two codewords which differ in exactly 3 places.

Hamming codes are examples of an important class of codes known as *linear codes*. You can think of linear codes in many ways:

1. A linear code of length $n$ is a linear subspace of $\{0,1\}^n$. The dimension of the code is known as the *rate* $k$.
2. A linear code is a code which is closed under XOR, that is, the XOR of any two codewords is again a codeword. It turns out that the number of codewords is always a power of 2, say $2^k$. The parameter $k$ is known as the *rate*.
3. A linear code is a way of encoding $k$-bit messages using $n$ bits. The original bits of the message are put in fixed places, and every other bit is an XOR of a certain fixed subset of the message bits. For example, the SEC(7,4) code encodes a 4-bit message $x,y,z,w$ using 7 bits:
   $$
   x \oplus y \oplus w, x \oplus z \oplus w, x, y \oplus z \oplus w, y, z, w
   $$

The minimal distance of a linear code is also the minimal Hamming weight of a non-zero codeword. So the fact that Hamming codes have minimum distance 3 means that (1) every non-zero codeword has at least 3 ones, (2) there exists a codeword having exactly 3 ones.

We have mentioned three parameters: the length of the code $n$, the rate of the code $k$, and the minimal distance $d$. There is no exact relation between these three parameters, though there are various  bounds relating the three quantities. One of these bounds is the Hamming bound:
$$
\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor \frac{d-1}{2}\rfloor} \binom{n}{\ell}\leq 2^{n-k}.
$$
For example, for the SEC(7,4) code this gives
$$
\binom{7}{0} + \binom{7}{1} \leq 2^{7-4}.
$$
You can check that equality holds, and indeed this is the case for all Hamming codes. Codes for which equality holds are called *perfect codes*. Apart from a few trivial and exceptional cases, Hamming codes are (essentially) the only perfect codes.